# How to generate a URL for ASP.NET MVC without string names

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to generate a URL for ASP.NET MVC without string names? I.e. I have Index action in HomeController. Using strings I would go for

```
@Url.Action("Index","Home")
```

but I would like to avoid use of string. I remember seeing a new way how to do this without strings, but I cannot find it anywhere now. The only code that I have found was

```
@(Url.Action<HomeController>(x=>x.Index()))
```

but that does not work for me. Error given is

```
The non-generic method 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action()' cannot be used with type arguments.
```

My ASP.NET MVC version is 5.2.3. If the above is only for 6+, is there any way to make achieve what I want?

Comment: The answer is no and what is wrong with the strings???

Comment: Does not survive refactoring, thought that would be obvious.... Also, it would be nice if you did not downvote questions you do not understand:)

Comment: Oh really? Can you explain how the code you trying to come up with would help in terms of refactoring? Because to me you are just trying to re-invent the wheel which is completely a waste of time. KISS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nuget package for that:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures/

this way you can do things like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<MyController>(x => x.MyMethod(a), "text") %>
<%= Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<MyController>(x => x.MyMethod(a)) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out T4MVC: https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC